# Fine Uploader cannot upload the file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using the file uploader jquery plugin in order to have ajax file uploading on my site. However I just cannot figure out what is going wrong and why it doesn't work.

Plugin: http://fineuploader.com/index.html

My code:

I took the code directly from their demo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$fub = $('#fine-uploader-basic');
$messages = $('#messages');

var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
  button: $fub[0],
  action: 'http://localhost/script/file_upload/upload_test',
  debug: true,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
  sizeLimit: 204800, // 200 kB = 200 * 1024 bytes
  onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
    $messages.append('<div id="file-' + id + '" class="alert" style="margin: 20px 0 0"></div>');
  },
  onUpload: function(id, fileName) {
    $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info')
                    .html('<img src="client/loading.gif" alt="Initializing. Please hold."> ' +
                          'Initializing ' +
                          '“' + fileName + '”');
  },
  onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total) {
    if (loaded < total) {
      progress = Math.round(loaded / total * 100) + '% of ' + Math.round(total / 1024) + ' kB';
      $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                      .html('<img src="client/loading.gif" alt="In progress. Please hold."> ' +
                            'Uploading ' +
                            '“' + fileName + '” ' +
                            progress);
    } else {
      $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info')
                      .html('<img src="client/loading.gif" alt="Saving. Please hold."> ' +
                            'Saving ' +
                            '“' + fileName + '”');
    }
  },
  onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
      $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                      .addClass('alert-success')
                      .html('<i class="icon-ok"></i> ' +
                            'Successfully saved ' +
                            '“' + fileName + '”' +
                            '<br><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '">');
    } else {
      $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                      .addClass('alert-error')
                      .html('<i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> ' +
                            'Error with ' +
                            '“' + fileName + '”: ' +
                            responseJSON.error);
    }
  }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fine-uploader-basic" class="btn btn-success">
  <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Click to upload
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

PHP:

```
public function upload_test() {
  $upload = move_uploaded_file('./user_files', $_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name']);
  if($upload) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => $upload));
  }
}
```

I think the problem is with the PHP, but I can't figure out what im doing wrong. Please help before I go insane.

Thank you.

Comment: It says the file cannot be uploaded with an error of undefined. The folder has the right permissions and all. I can't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didn't read ur js and html part, but you need to change your PHP part.
look at how he do it

[fine-uploader PHP](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php)

Comment: @RayNicholus, which php file in github are you referring to?

Comment: @Stranger This answer was contributed by TianLoon.  I simply updated the original link, since it was broken.

Comment: OK, but do you know which file he is talking about?

Comment: @RayNicholus,do you mind to help me out with fine-uploader issue?

Comment: @Stranger Please open up a new thread describing your problem and tag it "fine-uploader".

Comment: @Stranger, i guess u wanna look at the "qqFileUploader.php"

Answer (score 1):

Remove `action: 'http://localhost/script/file_upload/upload_test',` and change with

```
request: {
            // path to server-side upload script
        endpoint: 'script/file_upload/upload_test/php.php'
         }
```

Also in your php.php file uncomment:

```
$allowedExtensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "bmp", "png");
$sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
$uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
$result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads/'); //folder for uploaded files
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps here is my setup:

-- jquery.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Fine Uploader Demo</title>
        <link href="client/fineuploader.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="fine-uploader"></div>

        <script src="client/jquery.fineuploader-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          function createUploader() {
            var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
              debug: true,  
              // Pass the HTML element here
              element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
              // or, if using jQuery
              // element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
              // Use the relevant server script url here
              // if it's different from the default “/server/upload”
              request: {
                endpoint: 'php.php'

              }
            });
          }

          window.onload = createUploader;
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

--- php.php (in the same folder as the jquery.html)

the following lines have been uncommented:

```
    // list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
    $allowedExtensions = array();
    // max file size in bytes
    $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    //the input name set in the javascript
    $inputName = 'qqfile';

    $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit, $inputName);

    $result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads/');
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

uploads folder has 777 permissions

MAMP NOTE: A stream_copy_to_stream() error will be thrown on upload.
Solution:
Change Line 58 in the php.php from
$temp = tmpfile();
to
$temp = fopen("php://temp", "wb"); //$temp = tmpfile();

hope this helps someone.

Comment: I followed this example but the fileuploader isnt being displayed in my UI. Any hints as to why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a lot of people having trouble dealing with the server side script to handle the uploaded file. I needed some time to figure out how to write my own script to store the uploaded file in the database. This code example below will be very illustrative for those who are experiencing the same issue.

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['qqfile'];
$uploadDirectory = 'uploads';
$target = $uploadDirectory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file['name'];
$result = null;
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $result = array('success'=> true);
    $result['uploadName'] = $file['name'];
} else {
    $result = array('error'=> 'Upload failed');
}
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Of course, you have to adjust the name of your upload directory. It should work fine with the javascript below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#basicUploadSuccessExample')[0],
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: "server/php/example.php"
        }
    });
});
```

Just make sure you included all *.js in your html.

Comment: is the php you posted called  'example.php" ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem uploading to the folder as well.  In order to get more information I changed the **qqFileUploader.php** line **59** to:

```
if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory) || !is_executable($uploadDirectory))
{
return array('error' =>"Server error. Uploads directory isn't writable or executable. CUR_DIR: " . getcwd() . " DIR: " . $uploadDirectory);
}
```

After doing that I saw the problem was that it was looking for the folder in my php directory as apposed to the root directory.

I changed 
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload('up/');
to 
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload('../up/');
problem was resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

"File uploader", I'm assuming?

Have you done any basic debugging, e.g. adding error handling to your php code? Your code is broke on multiple levels:

1) move_upload_file requires a destination **FILE** name. You're providing only a directory:

```
move_uploaded_file('/path/to/destination/on/server.txt', $_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name']);
```

2) You're not checking of the upload acctually succeeded.

```
if($_FILES['qqfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     die("UPload failed with error code " . $_FILES['qqfile']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: No, Fine is fine :D follow the link he posted

Comment: I am using the fine uploader, however I just tried what you suggested and nothing changed. I still get the same error/problem.